# storing arrays into object datatype into firestore in android and iOS(swift)

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I  have 2 arrays like 
phonenumber[1,2,3]
amount[10,20,30]
I need to store the data in a single document like 
field1: 1
field2: 10

> The code I tried is

I took the object like 
**

```
public class Pojo {
    String invitee;
    Map<Integer,Integer>phoneAmount;
    public Pojo(String invitee, Map<Integer, Integer> phoneAmount)
    {
      this.invitee = invitee;
        this.phoneAmount=phoneAmount;
    }
}**
```

And in another class

```
 Map<int[], int[]> phoneAmount = new HashMap<>();
               phoneAmount.put(phonenumber,amount);


db.collection("Split").document("invitees").set(phoneAmount).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!");
                }
            })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e);
                        }
                    });
```

It shows error like 
 *java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not serialize object. Maps with non-string keys are not supported
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzejw.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzejw.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzejw.zzbp(Unknown Source)*

Comment: try using pojo class with one `String field` and one `Map<int,int> phoneAmount` and a constructor `public YourPojoClass(String title, Map<int,int> phoneAmount )` . By this you can add items to `phoneAmount` object like `phoneAmount.put(phoneNumber, amount);` and then add document to collection reference like `db.collection("Split").document("lahari").set(yourPojoClass)` after creating object of your PojoClass like `MyPojo pojo= new MyPojo ("invite", phoneAmount );`

Comment: @MohammedFarhan can you show me an example of this scenario. I am in confusion state

Comment: please follow Alex answer below, its similar to my comment and will suffice your requirement.

Comment: Thanks @MohammedFarhan

Comment: Check here [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays):

> Although Cloud Firestore can store arrays, it does not support querying array members or updating single array elements.

This approach is one that I personally don't recommend it to be used. One of the many reasons also Firebase recommends against using arrays is that it makes the security rules impossible to write.

However, you can still model this kind of data by leveraging the other capabilities of Cloud Firestore.

Let's take an example. Suppose you have a database which look like this:

```
{
    title: "My Book",
    categories: [
        "science",
        "computer science",
        "technology"
    ]
}
```

You need to know that if you want to query for all `books` that are part of the "science" category, using this data structure, there is no way to perform this query.

To solve this, you can consider an alternative data structure, where each category is the key in a map and all values are `true`.

```
{
    title: "My Book",
    categories: {
        "science": true,
        "computer science": true,
        "technology": true
    }
}
```

And to query your database you can use this query:

```
db.collection("books")
    .whereEqualTo("categories.science", true)
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {/* ... */});
```

For your particular case, you can use a database structure that looks like this:

```
{
    title: "phonenumber",
    categories: {
        "12345": true,
        "67890": true,
        "43215": true
    }
}
```

To query, please use the following code:

```
db.collection("phonenumbers")
    .whereEqualTo("categories.12345", true)
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {/* ... */});
```

**Edit 13 Aug 2018:**

According to the updated documentation regarding [array membership](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership), now it is possible to filter data based on array values using `whereArrayContains()` method. A simple example would be:

```
CollectionReference citiesRef = db.collection("cities");
citiesRef.whereArrayContains("regions", "west_coast");
```

> This query returns every city document where the regions field is an array that contains west_coast. If the array has multiple instances of the value you query on, the document is included in the results only once.

Comment: I need to query the phone number

Comment: @Alex Mamo, Hello Again. This must be the answer for OP. Please give OP the structure of POJO class.

Comment: what do u mean by op and pojo class

Comment: Please see my updated answer. OP is `Original Poster` and a `POJO class` is `Plain Old Java Object`.

Comment: kk I got it How to add to database

Comment: [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) is the official documentation on how to add data to Cloud Firestore. I recommend you add data using a `Map`.

Comment: I need to create an object class and need to define these 2 arrays @Alexo

Comment: As i already explained you in my answer, don't store data in arrays, you'll not be able to query later, store the data using a `Map`. Give it a try.

Comment: Your error says very clearly what's going on: `Maps with non-string keys are not supported`. You cannot use arrays as keys in you `Map`. Have you tried my solution?

Comment: @Alex In your case you said <string,boolean> but i need is <int , int> like  field1 :12345 and  field2 : 10. I have tried

Comment: Yes, because this the only way in which you can solve this. Using `<int , int>` is not possible.

Comment: @Alexo is there any other case to store the data like this then

Comment: To be able to query and modify data later, no, there is not!